# problem in string by replace occurance

Tags: iphone, string, replace, nsstring

i am getting the problem when i get the result from the xml api web service i use

```
NSString *productName = [[paramName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""] mutableCopy];
```

paramName is the argument of the function, but it can't replace the \ string which are on database

please help me out... thanks.

i only want to replace \ to none @"" but its not working now... please help me.. !!

i tried before its working but its not working now .. !! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably, you meant `@"\\"`, not `@"\""`. It looks like you're trying to kill quotes, not backslashes.